# Does not name type and was not declared error

Tags: arduino

Was trying to make a vibration detector and followed the tutorial from manufacturer site where I bought the Arduino but I got errors. 
I tried changing

```
unsigned char state = 0;
```

to

```
unsigned char state;
state =0;
```

No luck.

**Errors are:**

```
error: 'digital' does not name type
'blink' was not declared in this scope
'state' was not declared in this scope
```

**Codes:**

```
int SensorLED = 13;                              //define LED digital pin 13
int SensorINPUT = 3;                           // connect tilt sensor to   interrupt 1 in
digital pin 3
unsigned char state = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(SensorLED, OUTPUT);      //configure LED as output mode
pinMode(SensorINPUT, INPUT);     //configure tilt sensor as input mode
//when low voltage changes to high voltage, it triggers interrupt 1 and runs the blink function
attachInterrupt(1, blink, RISING);
}


void loop(){
if(state!=0){                                                     // if state is not 0
state = 0; 　                                                   // assign state value 0
digitalWrite(SensorLED,HIGH); 　             // turn on LED
delay(500); 　                                               // delay for 500ms
}
else{
digitalWrite(SensorLED,LOW);                 // if not, turn off LED
}
}


void blink(){                                              // interrupt             function blink()
state++;                                                    //once trigger the interrupt, the state keeps increment
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
unsigned char state = 0;
```

and

```
unsigned char state;
state =0;
```

are exactly the same thing.

What is the meaning of `digital pin 3` line in the code. You have already defined `SensorINPUT = 3`, and making it `INPUT` will make pin `D3` as input pin.

So just remove that line and code will compile fine. Rest of the error seems due to this line only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not commenting on functionality but errors can be fixed like this:

```
const byte SensorLED = 13;
const byte SensorINPUT = 3;


volatile byte state = LOW;

void blink(void)
{
  state = !state;
}

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(SensorLED, OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(SensorINPUT, INPUT);     
  attachInterrupt(1, blink, RISING);
}


void loop()
{
   digitalWrite(SensorLED, state);
   delay(500);
}
```